# The next mission is not opening

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I don’t know how to start the next mission as I completed 50% of the game and now I am finishing all Strangers and Freaks missions.

There is one mission as T but it cannot be accessed. Can anyone tell me how to start the mission of all characters?

Comment: Where is this T? This is useful to check what mission it is.